# Can not install firebase tools

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I tried to install Firebase all this morning. I follow the tutorial officially on setup Firebase hosting with the command line:
`npm install -g firebase-tools`
But it keep having trouble with error, here's the error message

```
pm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 647 packages, and audited 648 packages in 10s

38 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

11 vulnerabilities (8 moderate, 3 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
pshyduc@pshyducs-Air ~ % npm audit
found 0 vulnerabilities
pshyduc@pshyducs-Air ~ % npm audit fix

up to date, audited 1 package in 60ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
pshyduc@pshyducs-Air ~ %
```

I already search and following steps on [npm support](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally)

But on step 5 it said, do note that I don't know how to create or modify profile on VSCode so I go straight for `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global`

```
pshyduc@pshyducs-Air ~ % source ~/.profile
source: no such file or directory: /Users/pshyduc/.profile
```

Appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

After finding along, I finally found a solution, it's hidden in the Firebase Documentation.
Not very user friendly
Just use this command and you'll be all good
`curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash`

Comment: Please close this question